# Logarithmic Differentiation

Tags: derivatives, logarithms

When do we use :  $ \ln(ab) = \ln a + \ln b $ and when do we use : $ \ln |y| = \ln |f_1(x)| + \ln |f_2(x)| + \cdots + \ln |f_n(x)| $ ?

It is stated that we use the second form of log differentiation when, $y = f_1(x)f_2(x)\cdots f_n(x)$ is a product of nonzero functions.

What do they mean by product of nonzero functions?

Example given for second differentiation:

Find $dy/dx$ if $$ y =\frac{x \cos (x)}{\sqrt{\csc (x)}}. $$

Comment: $g(x)\ne 0$ is a non-zero function.

Comment: I think it is better to ask one question in a single post. You can always ask another question unless it is related to the same question.

Comment: @Hawk Oh, no its not a question. I just provided the example which was used to show the use of the second log differentiation :)

Comment: Okay, that is fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They mean that
$$y(x) = f_1(x) \times f_2(x) \times \ldots \times f_n(x)$$
where none of the terms on the right-hand side are zero.

Then you have
$$
\ln |y| = \ln \left| \prod_{k=1}^n f_k(x) \right|
        = \ln \left( \prod_{k=1}^n \left| f_k(x) \right| \right)
        = \sum_{k=1}^n \ln \left| f_k(x) \right|
$$

Rewriting equivalently in more usual notation:
$$\begin{split}
\ln |y|
 &= \ln \left| f_1(x) \times f_2(x) \times \ldots \times f_n(x) \right| \\
 &= \ln \left( \left| f_1(x) \right| \times
               \left| f_2(x) \right| \times \ldots \times
               \left| f_n(x) \right| \right) \\
 &= \ln \left| f_1(x) \right| + \ln \left| f_2(x) \right|
                              + \ldots + \ln \left| f_n(x) \right|.
\end{split}$$

Comment: (+1)...but do you think that such critical symbols might frighten a new user? :)

Comment: Oh..i got it, just read through it again. So, for the first kind, positive functions are used. For the second kind, both positive and negative functions are used, as they specify non-zero functions

Comment: @Phantom yes, exactly

Answer (score 1):

A function $f(x)$ is said to be non-zero if for any $x \in \mathbb R$ $f(x) \ne 0$ ,i.e does not have a value $0$.

This is necessary because the function $\log_a(x)$ is undefined at $x=0$.

After that it is simply an application of the law,

$$\log_k(ab) = \log_k(a) +\log_k(b)$$
For proof,

$$\text{Let }k^x = a, k^y = b$$

$$\implies \log_k(a)=x, \log_k(b)=y$$

$$ab=k^xk^y=k^{x+y}$$

$$\implies \log_k(ab) = x+y$$